# Error when using concurrently to run frontend and backend in the same project

Tags: reactjs, concurrently

It is giving me this error when I am using concurrently to run the frontend and backend folder with concurrently. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance.
[image: code with error]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the error. so I had to remove the app and index from the frontend folder and put it in src. and then I edited the script tag like this:

```
"start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\"  \"cd src/backend && nodemon server\"",
```

So it was a structural error.